# Internal Server Error with perl on Big Sur

Tags: macos, perl

I have a series of perl scripts I am unsing since many years. Now I want to modify one of them and copy the code into a new file with another name (modified with _n) It is in the same location and with the same permissions. Running it I get

> **Internal Server Error**
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

In the server log I read

> End of script output before headers

I tried the same thing with other files that all work ok on my system, with the same result: Internal server error.

I also used a very simple script as

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

use strict;
use warnings;

print "Hello, world!<br />\n";
```

with the same result.

What is the difference that leads to this error?

MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3
Perl 5.34, reinstalled
BBEdit 14.0.1
Fetch 6.8.2

Comment: *"Now I want to modify one of them and copy the code into a new file with another name (modified with _n) "* : Does the old script still work?

Comment: *"In the server log I read"* : Is this Apache web server?

Answer (score 0):

adding -w to the shebang solved the problem. Silly...